# Gstreamer text overlay from variables on memory

Tags: gstreamer, pango, pangocairo, freedesktop.org, gst-launch-1.0

Im running the command such as following and this command broadcasts the video to ethernet port. But here is my question that how I can add overlay onto video where overlay values are stored in shared memory and may change any time.

`gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! video/xraw,format=NV16, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1 ! omxh264enc ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.5 port=5004`

Should I run another thread to do it?

Comment: You are talking about doing this from code and not the command line, right?

Comment: Yes from a C or C++ code @Mike

Comment: I did this via a GTKOverlay at the receiving end and then drew on top of the video stream. If you wanted the result to definitely go over the network, I suppose you could (somehow) capture the output and transmit that.
Would this be any use to you? It might take some time to extract the minimum code from my project.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, Im getting video data from framebuffer on FPGA using only command above. So, how I manipulate it using GTKOverlay? Actually is it possible?

Comment: I think I see what you're needing. If it's text then there's a textoverlay plugin but I've put some info in my answer. Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [compositor](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/compositor/index.html?gi-language=c#compositor) or [videomixer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videomixer/index.html?gi-language=c) plugin is what you are looking for. I've never used them myself so I can't be much help, but there's a nearly complete list of plugins [here](https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/plugins.html?gi-language=c).

Answer (score 0):

You said you're trying to do this from c or c++ code, you can do this using textoverlay plugin, for example, you name your [textoverlay](https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/pango-1.0/textoverlay.html) element "textsrc", then when you need to change the text value:

> GstElement *textsrc; textsrc =
> gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up(GST_BIN(element), "textsrc");

Then using `g_object_set` you can change the value for different parameters that correspond to what you want, `text` for text you want shown, more about the different parameters can be found in the documentation.